# Add multiple elements in a div without the others losing their values

Tags: javascript, html

When I add an input using the add button, change its value, then add another input, the inputs that are already in the container lose their value.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let container = document.getElementById('container');

btn.onclick = function() {
  container.innerHTML += `<input type="number" max="10" min="1" value="1"><br>`;
}
```

```html
<button id="addBtn">add element</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `insertAdacentHTML` instead of `+=`ing to the `innerHTML` of the container. That way, the existing elements don't get corrupted:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let container = document.getElementById('container');

btn.onclick = function() {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="number" max="10" min="1" value="1"><br>`);
};
```

```html
<button id="addBtn">add element</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Changing the `innerHTML` of a container will effectively clear anything not present in element string, when read in HTML. So, set `.value`s don't get preserved, nor do event listeners.

`insertAdjacentHTML`, on the other hand, doesn't re-parse any of the existing children - it *only* inserts adjacent HTML, leaving everything else alone.

You can also create the element with `createElement` and append with `appendChild`, but that's a bit verbose when there are lots of attributes.

Comment: Thanks man that worked. Can finally start working on this shopping cart :D.

Comment: @AmineAboutaieb Please mark as the right answer and feel free to upvote, if it solves your issue. To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="btn2">add</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var add='<input type="text" value="hello" readonly />';
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        $('p').append(add);
    });
});
</script>
```